# Staging table has no data during refresh times (Populated using a Stored Procedure)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My work has a stored procedure that empties and then repopulates a SQL staging table multiple times a day every now and then the table returns with no values when it is refreshing, this is causing me difficulty and I need access to the data in the table. What can I do to fix this?

I was thinking maybe create a view on top of the staging table or maybe the stored procedure is coded wrong it can maybe be modified

the procedure begins with the following code:

```
create or replace Procedure <ProcedureName>
as
Begin

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE table <TableName>';
     insert into <TableName> 
END
```

Comment: lock the table or use transactions

Comment: "table returns with no values when it is refreshing" - this is a given and expected behaviour. What are you exactly trying here, do you want to have access for the data that was in table before truncate by procedure or you want to have access to data as it is being inserted - which is not feasible!

Comment: What you may be missing is that `truncate` is DDL so it implicitly commits; once that has executed the table is then really empty for everyone until the insert has been run and committed. If you deleted and then inserted then those two operations can be part of one transaction so it wouldn't be empty to others until commit; but truncate doesn't work like that. Presumably you're truncating instead of deleting for a reason though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the `truncate table` and the commit after the `insert into` transaction the table will effectively be empty.

One way of solving this is to use the "exchange partitioning" technique. It is pretty well explained on the web. The idea is that the data is loaded in a staging table with a single partition and when the loading is complete, the partition of the staging table is exchanged with the partition in the main table. This process is instant - at no point the table is empty.

Comment: Thanks i'll try to implement the partitioning of the staging table.